# Android implement text group

Tags: android

[image]

I have seen an app with an activity  which display a group of text with transparent background and white rounded border on top and bottom  as you see. Except transparency i don't know how to implement. The text are clickable. Any ideas?

this is what i did but it's not what i looking for

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"   >

<solid
    android:color="#35888888" >
</solid>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FB6E25" >
</stroke>

<padding
    android:left="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp"    >
</padding>

<corners
    android:radius="11dp"   >
</corners>
```

and my layout

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/box"
android:layout_width="220dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.18"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="TextView" />
<TextView          
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="1px" 
  android:background="#FF9A66" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget34"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.56"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

  <TextView          
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="1px" 
  android:background="#FF9A66" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget35"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.56"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:text="TextView" />
 <TextView          
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="1px" 
  android:background="#FF9A66" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget36"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.56"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
  <TextView          
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="1px" 
  android:background="#FF9A66" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/widget37"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.56"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:background="#99000000"
      android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: what did u try ??? its simple, framelayout on top of it has linearlayout and main layout maybe relative or linear as suits u

Comment: and the white rounded border?

Comment: you could use shapedrawable or just a transparent background  for the view rounder border. find which one easy for you and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a rounded rectangle [via a `ShapeDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) and apply it to the background of a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: i updated my question and use shapeDrawable but the result is not the same as what i looking for